# Potential convention sponsorship opportunities

Tags: discussion, promotion

The Stack Exchange team is open to the possibility of sponsoring conventions as a way of promoting a Stack Exchange site (see [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)).  I'd like to compose a list of possible conventions/trade shows/festivals who's attendees would fit the audio.se target audience.

**Sweetwater's [GearFest](http://www.sweetwater.com/emails/gearfest2010/)**
***Fort Wayne, Indiana***
I've attended the Sweetwater GearFest for the last couple of years.  They draw a large number of musicians, engineers, and producers ranging from hobbyists to pros.  They have a place for vendors and sponsors to set up booths.

Answer (score 4):

[The Winter NAMM show](http://www.namm.org/thenammshow/2011) is a trade show that I've gone to a few times.  As a trade show, the audience is generally professional musicians, engineers, and companies who sell products and services in the music industry.

It's a pretty big event and the people who attend tend to be very knowledgable within their scope.  I'm not sure how many questions they would ask but if the right ones found the site, they'd have some great answers!

Comment: Looks interesting, I see the 2011 show already happened.  Looks like they have a [summer show](http://www.namm.org/summer/2011) in July as well.

Comment: Yeah, the Winter show just happened last weekend.  It rocked and I learned a lot (I was in on a visitor badge; I'm not associated with any member organization).  I tried to talk about the site a bit but there didn't seem to be an easy way to get large numbers of people interested.

Answer (score 2):

The [Musikmesse Frankfurt](http://www.musikmesse.de/) is *the* place to be for people here (Germany and probably Europe).

> Musikmesse - the biggest fair for
>   musical instruments, live music and
>   the music business!
>
> Musikmesse in Frankfurt am Main is the
>   world’s most international fair for
>   musical instruments, sheet music,
>   music production and marketing, and
>   has been the foremost meeting place
>   for the musical-instrument industry
>   for over 25 years.
>
> [...]
>
> Musikmesse 2011 will be held in Frankfurt am Main from 6 to 9 April.

Generally, hiring some trade fair girls will be crucial for SE imo.

- http://www.crn.de/panorama/artikel-81450.html
- http://www.delamar.de/events/musikmesse-2008-mehr-messe-babes-1650/
- http://www.synthtopia.com/content/2009/04/09/2009-musikmesse-photos/

Comment: I took out the embedded pic - just a bit over the line I think.  There's plenty of pics in your links that get your point across.  Thanks for the post in general though - looks like a good opportunity!

Comment: @BenV well I thought a picture is worth more than a thousand words, while the links alone are worth maybe... 10 words. :->

Answer (score 2):

If we can get ourselves known in the [AES](http://www.aes.org) (Audio Engineering Society), I think we get ourselves into the largest community known to professional audio engineers world-wide. The next convention will be in May, in London, and thousands of professional audio engineers will be there. If we can spread the word out there, I think we will open the doors getting a whole host of experts in.

We (me and other ex-students) used to represent the Conservatory of The Hague there, so I know there are possibilities for "educational" instances / initiatives. I am not a member of the AES at the moment.

I think we could start by getting a few of us in there in London, with full-color flyers that we can easily spread out. Everybody in there is potentially interested, and we would probably be the first Q&A site doing something like that on an AES convention.